# SharePoint Rest API - Mentioned users in a custom list item's comments are not being displayed correctly

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, custom-list, comments, custom-list-actions

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Add a custom list item in SharePoint.
2. Make a comment to the list item and mention a user or users in the comment.
3. Make a request to the Rest API.

We get the following response in the 'text' field of the CommentValue:
`"text": "@mention&#123;0&#125; @mention&#123;1&#125; "`

However, the same issue does not exist for comments in the Document Library.
Response: `"text": "<a data-sp-mention-user-id=\"test1@test.onmicrosoft.com\" href=\"mailto&#58;test1@test.onmicrosoft.com\" tabindex=\"-1\">@Test1</a> <a data-sp-mention-user-id=\"test2@test.onmicrosoft.com\" href=\"mailto&#58;test2@test.onmicrosoft.com\" tabindex=\"-1\">@Test2</a> \n"`